# Details des imports contact evenement et activité

Tags: import

Bonjour,

Où peut on trouver la dicumentation qui détaillent les dfférence entre les champ d'import pour les contact activiy et

Comment: Bonjour. I think you are asking about the difference in the import fields between importing Participants and importing Activities. It would help to understand why you are asking from a structural point of view. There are situations where one might say 'should i do this as an Event or an Activity'. To help answer it would be good to know what the scenario is.

Comment: also if you use a CSV and do an Activity Import and also a Participant Import then you should quickly see what 'required' fields each of them have. J'espere que ca vous aidez.

Comment: Hello

Yes indeed, I have to import a structured database in the following way
We have moral person who has more than one address and each address has contacts.
Each legal person is connected to an organization
IF you can help me find out how this translates in civicrm.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation est ici: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/fr/latest/common-workflows/importing-data-into-civicrm/

Le plupart concernent l'import des contacts, mais il y a instructions pour activites et evenements a la fin.

*Please excuse my french*

Comment: HI Craig Almond

Thank for your answer, this is help me.
For information your french is correct :)

Shakta

Comment: Merci, Shakta. C'est plus de vingt ans depuis je l'etudais.

Comment: lol, Like me in english